# What is the number of ways to swim on the same set of dates?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, problem-solving

A school allowed the students of a class to go to swim during the days March $11th$ to March $15$, $2019$. The minimum number of students the class should have had that ensures that at least two of them went to swim on the same set of dates is?

I concluded that in the given $5$ days we can set to students. So to get the least number of students we can get $(5*2+1)=11$ but the answer is given $33$. Can anyone explain this problem?

Comment: $~2^5 + 1.~$  There are $~2^5~$ possibilities, re a specific student either does or does not swim on each of the $~5~$ days.

Comment: But what if the student considered did not go to swim in any of the five days. Then we have only one student going to the swim in any of the given days which fails to show that any two students go swim on the same dates. Could you please help me understand that @user2661923?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation "in the given $5$ days we can set to students" (I think the $to$ is $2$ but I'm not sure). I ask for something more mathematical on your side. Like, you want to apply the pigeonhole/Dirichlet/box principle (that's why you added $1$ to $2 * 5$ I'm assuming) so tell me what the pigeons are and what the holes are and I can try to see if that matches with the first comment (which is correct)

Comment: I am trying to assume 11 students (pigeons) and 5 days (holes) .

Comment: Wait, I think my argument does not give the $least$ ways to get the answer but I fail to understand why 2^5+1  is the answer. Any one student can have two choices for each day and we get 2^5 choices , but the question asks the number of students, not the number of choices. I am unable to understand this @SarveshRavichandranIyer.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas The question asks "what is the minimum number of students such that you can say, with certainty, that two people went to swim on the same *set of dates*?" For any student, there are $2^5$ choices of which day they want to go to swim and which day they don't. So the pigeons are the students, and the pigeonholes are the "sets of dates" (e.g. one pigeonhole is "Mar $11$,Mar $13$", another pigeonhole is "Mar $12$, Mar $13$, Mar $14$", another pigeonhole is "no day" and so on). Now there are $2^5$ pigeonholes, and so you need $2^5+1$ pigeons.

Comment: Oho , now I got it. Thank you very much @SarveshRavichandranIyer